# Открыть раздел реестра. Win32API

Tags: c, winapi

Как открыть какой нибудь раздел ключа реестра, к которому нельзя без прав обращаться? Можно как-то манипулируя привилегиями открыть? Или другие способы? Например я хочу в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY` добавить подраздел через `RegCreateKeyEx` или значение через `RegSetValueEx`.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    HKEY hKey = nullptr;
    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SECURITY"), NULL, KEY_READ, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("OPENED"), TEXT("SUCCESS"), MB_OK);
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("TEST"), NULL, REG_SZ, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Естественно никакого меседж бокса не выскакивает.

Answer (score 0):

И зачем бы нужна была такая система прав, если бы ее можно было при желании обойти? Так что нет, если если у вас нет прав доступа, значит доступа и не будет. Если же у вас получилось "манипулируя привилегиями" получить куда-то доступ, значит вы обнаружили дыру в системе.